# 3D scanner from Phone Camera

Tags: computer-vision, 3d-printing, 3d-reconstruction, 3d-model

[123D software](http://www.123dapp.com/catch) can construct a 3D model from photos taken from your phone. It doesn't process the photos in your phone.  Instead, it sends them to the cloud to create 3d model. How can i construct a 3d model like this **(only with one camera)**? I searched it but i can only find information on laser/procetor scanners (simple and desktop use only). I think 123D uses only IMU sensors and camera **why do they use the cloud**?  Can a beaglebone or rasperry pi create 3d models like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating 3D models with this method is very compute intensive, 123d uses many pictures (at least 20), and examines them for feature points that are common in several pictures and by examining how they change between pictures it can help build up a 3ds point cloud which is then textured using the pictures, this is very resource intensive, and could be done by a beaglebone or raspberry pi, but it would take a very long time. If you wanted to make your own system to 3d scan objects with cameras it is soing to be a lot easier to have an array of them pre calibrated to work in sync to generate models. This is how many professional setups work.